# jqgrid - filter results with multiple selects like excel

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

i would like to use multiple filter options for all columns with using select form object.

When a columns filter selected, other select object options may filled to this selection.

Clearly, i want to filter jqrid columns as same excel filter feature.

I use php for server side.

Thank your very much for your help and suggestions already now.

Comment: Could you explain in other words what you mean under "other select object options may filled to like request results as excel"? Do you already tried to use Toolbar Searching http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching? What exactly you want to implement?

Comment: i have 7 columns. i want you use filter on all colums. all colums filter make by select form objects. clearly i want filter columns same as excel. i mean, after a colums filter selection, others columns filter options may fill to this selection.

Comment: What about the usage of the Toolbar Searching (see http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/customfilter5.htm)?

Comment: If i explain over your example. When i select sport choice from category column's filter, sub category column's filter select object options must be just football and formel 1 or the exact opposite of sub category column's filter selection.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to implement should be combination of the usage of Toolbar Searching (see [this demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/customfilter5.htm) as an example and the usage of 'change' custom event handle as [dataEvents](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asearch_config#colmodel_options) inside of the `searchoptions`. Inside of your 'change' handle you can make an ajax request to the server and then rebuild `<select>` element of the second drop-down list.

You can find more examples used the same technique with `editoptions`. Both work based on the same idea. The technique is not simple, but it works. I recommend you to read [this thread](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/dynamically-populate-select-dropdown/).

Comment: @Kerberos: You welcome! If you will have problems with the implementation I could try to help you later.